# Custom Data Structure for Push, Pop and Dequeue operations in Constant Time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have asked this Question in one of the interview. Reproducing it.

**Write custom DS where Push(),Pop() and Dequeue() operations will be done in constant time.
e.g. input is 1,2,3,4 then we called pop(), 4 should be returned. If we call dequeue, 1 should be returned. Everything in O(1).**

I have answered, but wasn't sure if that was best w.r.t. Space Complexity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[doubly Linked List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) can provide it.

By having a pointer to both head and tail you can implement both `dequeue()` and `pop()` efficiently (`O(1)`).

Something along the lines of: (Assuming Garbage Collected language, and simplified version, not null/empty safe):

```
push(e):
  n = new Node(e)
  last.next = n
  n.previous = last
  last = n       
pop():
  e = last.value
  last.previous.next = null
  last = last.previous
  return e
dequeue():
  e = head.value
  head = head.next
  head.previous = null
  return e
```

Regarding space complexity:

The solution is `Theta(n)` space, it is easy to see that any sub-linear solution will not be able to store all the data - and will fail in some cases.

Comment: That's the exactly what I answered. Looking for better solution, if there is any.

Comment: @VallabhPatade xor linked list?

Comment: @amit: Don't you think you should update last=last.previous in pop() routine?

Comment: @amit : Me too, couldn't able to come up with more efficient solution than this. Let's assume this is the best solution that this problem can have.

Comment: @VallabhPatade: You might be able to use a dynamic circular array. You can make sure `space <= 2 * n * sizeof(element) + CONST`, but it will make the space complexity `O(1)` amortized and not worst case.